# Table update - use one column to update another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table that looks like this:

Table1

```
Val1    Val2       Type     Date          Key
NULL    110.1      T        11/30/2020    174
NULL    205.5      D        12/31/2020    133
NULL    360.7      T        11/30/2020    190
```

Key in this case is Unique. What I want to do is Set Val1 = Val2 where Type='T' and Date = '11/30/2020'

Does this look correct?

```
 Update t1
 set t1.Val1 = t2.Val2
 From Table1 t1
 JOIN Table1 t2
      on t1.Key = t2.Key
 Where t1.type='T' and t1.Date = '11/30/2020'
```

Desired results:

```
Val1     Val2       Type     Date          Key
110.1    110.1      T        11/30/2020    174
NULL     205.5      D        12/31/2020    133
360.7    360.7      T        11/30/2020    190
```

Comment: Did it work? Strange to be asking us rather than just trying it.

Comment: *"Is this look correct?"* Why not run the query, and find out if it works? or run the statement as a `SELECT` first, so you can see what rows would be updated, and new values that would be assigned. *You* are in a far better position to check that us, who don't have access to your instance.

Comment: Just a side note, I see that the columns are nullable. You might wanna check for nullity using `IS NULL`. Equality with null is a bit unintuitive, e.g. NULL = NULL can evaluate to `FALSE`. One way to avoid this is `set ansi_nulls on`

Comment: @prnvbn Presumably you meant `set ansi_nulls off`, this is only there for backwards compat and there are a number of things you cannot do when it is `off`. *You* might find it unintuitive, but that is how SQL is meant to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a `join`:

```
update table1
    Set Val1 = Val2
    where Type='T' and Date = '2020-11-30';
```

Note:  I recommend using dates in standard formats, so wither `'2020-11-30'` or `'20201130'`.

Comment: *If* the OP is using the older date and time data types (`datetime` and `smalldatetime`) I don't recommend `yyyy-MM-dd` as it is ambiguous; this is *not* the case for the newer data and time data types.

Comment: In what scenario would I need a join? I'm just curious. I guess I was overthinking it

Comment: @Koosh . . . Based on your question, you were overthinking it.  All the data you need is in one row.